# How to change the time zone in the pm2 logs

Tags: pm2

The following is the application delcaration json file

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "test_v2",
    "script"      : "bin/www",
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "ignore_watch" : ["[\\/\\\\]\\./", "node_modules"],
    "watch"       : true,
    "node_args"   : "--harmony",
    "cwd"         : "/root/src/test_v2",
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN": "xxx",
        "TZ": "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
  }]
}
```

To change the time zone, i had followed as commented at https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/560

But it does not work. The behavior is the same as thought the "TZ" is not present. I tried even hard coding the time zone to numeric value like "+08:00" which does not work. How to change the time zone in the logs.

Comment: I found that if you change your server timezone and restart the server, your server timezone would be used

Answer (score 3):

`log_date_format` in directly used with [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) in pm2 - [source](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/689612efb4337104be4e36e17c0a2f4d9fd064d1/lib/ProcessContainer.js#L130).

[The following](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) options are available in moment.

I don't think that timezone has been implemented in any way but you can remove `Z` and use the **UTC** time.

If you really need a timezone implementation, fire a feature issue on pm2.

Comment: There is an existing issue, https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3818 which is closed without code sample

Answer (score 1):

From that same [Github issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3818#issuecomment-569493369) mentioned above, this helped me:

First update the format (make sure server timezone is what you want)

```
pm2 restart 0 --log-date-format "HH:mm:ss DD-MM-YYYY Z"
```

save all processes

```
pm2 save
```

run these

```
npm i -G pm2 //if not latest 
pm2 update
```

Comment: It should be `pm2 restart 0 --log-date-format "HH:mm:ss DD-MM-YYYY Z"`